# Can make "target" take an argument?

Tags: c, makefile

lets say I am doing mk "target" to build something. Is it possible to pass an argument to it?
i.e. mk "target" "x" and it will do things accordingly? I know that I will be providing mk "target" an argument and I know its semantics, just dont know the name well in advance.

Possible?

Comment: What's `mk` - is that a synonym for `make`?

Comment: I thought he was talking about mknod for some reason.... or playing the new Mortal Kombat with your source....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to make use of [GNU Make's "Variables"](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Using-Variables.html):

```
$ cat Makefile

ifndef LOLCAKES
   LOLCAKES=1
endif

all:
   @echo $(LOLCAKES)

$ make all LOLCAKES=42
```

You didn't explain what you're trying to accomplish, so it's hard to know what kind of "argument" you're after.

Comment: Thanks much Tomalak. based on the argument which is a string, my "mk target" will look into different paths to do the make. So, string argument is basically a way for me to ask user for what dirs he/she wants to look into for make. does that explain? thanks again.

Comment: @hari: Sounds like this is your solution, then.

Comment: Sorry for my very little knowledge for make but you mean, should ask user to export an env variable and use it? I am not quite getting what you mean here by: echo $(LOLCAKES) under target all:

Comment: @hari: No, I am not using environment variables. Read the section in the manual about [make's variables](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Using-Variables.html).

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. So I can do : mk target name=x and have my makefile use "name" everywhere.

Comment: @hari: That's right. Do read the manual section for usage notes. In most places you'd write `$(name)` to get the variable's value.

Answer (score 2):

`make target x` will cause `make` to try to build `target` *and* `x`.  There's no way to have a modifier like you seem to be expecting.  A good solution can be to have rules with compound names:

```
target: target.debug target.release

target.release:
    # recipe for release build

target.debug:
    # recipe for debug build
```

Then you can use `target.debug`, `target.release`, or just `target`, and get some sane behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables:

```
$ cat Makefile 
all:
    @echo $(FOO)
$ FOO=bar make
bar
```