# How to pass argument to Makefile from command line?

Tags: command-line, parameters, makefile, arguments

How to pass argument to Makefile from command line?

I understand I can do

```
$ make action VAR="value"
$ value
```

with `Makefile`

```
VAR = "default"
action:
    @echo $(VAR)
```

How do I get the following behavior?

```
$ make action value
value
```

How about

```
$make action value1 value2
value1 value2
```

Comment: Similar: [Passing arguments to “make run”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2214575/55075)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run)

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You probably shouldn't do this; you're breaking the basic pattern of how Make works. But here it is:

```
action:
        @echo action $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

%:      # thanks to chakrit
    @:    # thanks to William Pursell
```

**EDIT:**
To explain the first command,

`$(MAKECMDGOALS)` is the list of "targets" spelled out on the command line, e.g. "action value1 value2".

`$@` is an [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) for the name of the target of the rule, in this case "action".

`filter-out` is a function that removes some elements from a list. So `$(filter-out bar, foo bar baz)` returns `foo baz` (it can be more subtle, but we don't need subtlety here).

Put these together and `$(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))` returns the list of targets specified on the command line other than "action", which might be "value1 value2".

Comment: `$(shell echo $(MAKECMDGOALS) | sed 's!^.* $@ !!')` to omit all targets before and just consider the following as arguments: `make target1 target2 action value1 value2`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance.  I've tried googling `%:` and `@:` and cannot find info on what those "directives" (or whatever they're called) do.  Could you please explain?

Comment: @Jon: The manual is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). The part consisting of `%:` and `@:` is a [rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rules). The target name `%` means that it is [a rule that matches anything](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules); that is, if Make can't find any other way to build the thing you tell it to build, it will execute that rule. The `@:` is a [recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax); the `:` means do nothing, and the `@` means do it silently.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been reading that manual and I didn't consider at first, that `%:` was actually `% :`, a wildcard type target name.  I don't see anything in that manual page regarding `@:` though... it does suggest that a "do-nothing" rule would simply have a `;` after the target specification, so, would it not be more accurate to write `% : ;` as the "wildcard do-nothing" rule?

Comment: `filter-out` doesn't work when the action is a dependency of the target specified on the command line, because `$@` will be set to the dependency's name, not the original argument called on the command line. Instead, I assign `MAKECMDGOALS` to a shell array and then remove the first element: `@ args=($(MAKECMDGOALS)); args=("$${args[@]:1}")`

Comment: fwiw, ":" is a synonym of "true" command, which is likely less cryptic. ":" isn't used often anymore, and brevity likely isn't worth it...?

Comment: @Beta using your solution (awesome, wow)--do you know how to suppress the output at the end of execution that says, `make: 'input1' is up to date`  for the various inputs?

Comment: @Beta this got me 90% of the way but if my arg is "le creuset" it will split on the space despite being wrapped in ". Is there a known workaround here?

Comment: "you're breaking the basic pattern of how Make works" - what do you mean by this? And what is the "correct" pattern?

Comment: This works for me but it outputs `make: *** No rule to make target 'value'.  Stop.`. How to prevent this?

Comment: If the argument is something like `make foo bar -- --param` this works fine, it resolves to `bar --param` -- but if we try to do `make foo bar -- --param=10` to pass in a value, for some reason it is just `bar` with `--param=10` stripped out. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Aha, got it -- if you require that flags be passed down as well, you'd want: `$(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS)) $(MAKEFLAGS)`

Comment: @abc123 that's because you have to add a tab before the @: instead of space.

Answer (score 41):

Here is a generic working solution based on @Beta's

I'm using GNU Make 4.1 with `SHELL=/bin/bash` atop my Makefile, so YMMV!

This allows us to accept extra arguments (by doing nothing when we get a job that doesn't match, rather than throwing an error).

```
%:
    @:
```

And this is a macro which gets the args for us:

```
args = `arg="$(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))" && echo $${arg:-${1}}`
```

Here is a job which might call this one:

```
test:
    @echo $(call args,defaultstring)
```

The result would be:

```
$ make test
defaultstring
$ make test hi
hi
```

Note! You might be better off using a "Taskfile", which is a bash pattern that works similarly to make, only without the nuances of Maketools. See https://github.com/adriancooney/Taskfile

Comment: It worked!! TO other people trying it out, make sure there is `tab` before `@echo`, not `space`.

Comment: This also works if the action (e.g., test:) is a dependency of the target specified on the command line.

Comment: This will execute the target `hi` if this target exist in the Makefile. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: @oz123 You might want to look into using environment variables, rather than positional arguments. You could also look at using a scripting language for this. As mentioned, bash has some useful patterns for this.

Comment: @M3D This only worked for me when I did: `make test args=hi` - am I being thick?

Answer (score 27):

Much easier aproach. Consider a task:

```
provision:
        ansible-playbook -vvvv \
        -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory \
        --private-key=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key \
        --start-at-task="$(AT)" \
        -u vagrant playbook.yml
```

Now when I want to call it I just run something like:

`AT="build assets" make provision`

or just:

`make provision` in this case `AT` is an empty string

Answer (score 10):

Few years later, want to suggest `just` for this: https://github.com/casey/just

```
action v1 v2=default:
    @echo 'take action on {{v1}} and {{v2}}...'
```

Answer (score 6):

You will be better of defining variables and calling your make instead of using parameters:

Makefile

```
action: ## My action helper
    @echo $$VAR_NAME
```

Terminal

```
> VAR_NAME="Hello World" make action
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

don't try to do this

```
$ make action value1 value2
```

instead create script:

```
#! /bin/sh
# rebuild if necessary
make
# do action with arguments
action "$@"
```

and do this:

```
$ ./buildthenaction.sh value1 value2
```

for more explanation why do this and caveats of makefile hackery read my answer to another very similar but seemingly not duplicate question: [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run/45003119#45003119)