# Forward command-line arguments to Makefile

Tags: makefile, mocha.js

I have a Makefile wrapping around mocha which can be called by `npm test`. There are several targets in the Makefile, which looks something like:

```
COMPILERS = --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
REPORTER = --reporter dot
TEST_DIR = test
SRC = -name test_*.coffee
RUNNER = ${TEST_DIR}/runner.coffee
MOCHA = NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ${COMPILERS} ${REPORTER} ${RUNNER} ${TEST_DIR}

all:
    $(MOCHA) $(shell find ${TEST_DIR} ${SRC})

subtest1:
    $(MOCHA) $(shell find ${TEST_DIR}/subtest1 ${SRC})

...
```

Now, this is being called from `package.json` as `npm test` where `npm test subtest1` runs only `subtest1`. However, it would be very nice to allow appending arbitrary `mocha` flags, so something like:

```
make subtest1 -g "some test I want to run"
```

This can be done by defining an `ARGS` variable, so typing:

```
make subtest1 ARGS="-g 'some test I want to run'"
```

but that's quite verbose.

Therefore, passing arguments through to Mocha would be really nice.

The closest I've come is defining `ARGS` at the top of the `Makefile`:

```
ARGS = $(filter-out all subtest1, $(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

and appending `ARGS` to the `MOCHA` variable. This can then be called as `make subtest1 -- -g "some test I want to run"`. That works, it runs the test, but `make` then stops with `make: *** No rule to make target`-g'.  Stop.`

That same error message is then presented when doing just `make -- -g "some test I want to run"`.

So, is there any way to continue down this `ARGS` path and somehow suppress make from attempting to run any targets found in `ARGS`, and therefore allowing both `all` to run, and that error message to not appear? Or should I change tack completely and there's some other way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass argument to Makefile from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273608/how-to-pass-argument-to-makefile-from-command-line)

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate - that question doesn't have multiple targets and doesn't work with them (at least as far as I can discern).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with that simply by adding a dummy rule for each argument, like this:

```
$(ARGS):
```

However you should not be reading your arguments from `MAKECMDGOALS`, it will cause all sorts of problems.

You could instead use a script or define aliases in your shell. Here's a rule that can help do that:

```
shortcut-%:
    @echo '$* () { make -C "$(CURDIR)" -f $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))) $* ARGS="$$(printf "%q " "$$@")"; }'
```

Use it like this:

```
eval `make shortcut-subtest1`
subtest1 -g test
```