# Makefile - Get arguments passed to make

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile like so:

```
.SILENT: #don't echo commands as we run them.

###
# here, set $1 (in the latter bash script) to the first make arg.
# $2 to the second one.
# et cetera.
# ($0 being set properly is optional)
###

foo:
    echo "you passed to make: $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6"
```

so i can do:

```
make foo
You passed to make: foo
```

(don't tell anyone, but i'm creating a 'make me a sandwich' thing)

Comment: Did you have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273608/how-to-pass-argument-to-makefile-from-command-line ? Moreover, in any case, you can get list of targets passed to make thanks to the variable MAKECMDGOALS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot "see" the full list of arguments of the **make** command in a Makefile. You can see the list of "targets" in the order they were entered on the command line, e.g.

```
make a   c b   d
```

will produce **$(MAKECMDGOALS)** with `a c b d`.

You can specifically check that something was set on the **make** command line, e.g.

```
make A=B C=D
```

will produce **$(A)** with `B`, and **$(C)** with `D`. But you will never know if it was `make A=B C=D` or `make C=D A=B` or `make A=F -B C=D A=B`.

If it is really important, you can wrap your make in a shell script, and have the full power of it:

```
make.sh a A=B c
```

calls

```
#!/bin/bash
make MAKECMDLINE="$*" $*
```

Now inside the Makefile, you can parse **$(MAKECMDLINE)** as you wish.

Note that some command-line options may disable your parser, e.g.

```
make A=B C=D -h
```

will never read your Makefile, and

```
make A=B C=D -f /dev/null
```

will also ignore your Makefile.

Comment: Doesn't make sometimes call itself, so wrapping make in a shell script  won't work?

Comment: Yes this is another limitation. I bet there are more…

Comment: Very enlightening

Comment: Actually: you can. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061796

Comment: @SantaXL this solution does not resolve the problem of non-target arguments (e.g. `A=B`)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 2019:** Wow, past-me was so stupid.

---

Alright, I figured out my own question.

You can create a shell script to have total control:

```
$ cat make.sh
if [ $1 = 'me' ]; then
    if [ $1 = 'a' ]; then
        if[ $3 = 'sandwich' ];then
            if [ `whoami` = 'root' ];
                echo "Okay."
                #todo: echo an actual sandwich in ascii.
            else
                echo "what? Make it yourself!"
            fi
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
fi

make $@

$ echo 'alias make="/home/connor/make.sh"' >> .bashrc
$ source .bashrc
```

...tada! now when you call make, it'll actually call the shell script, check if the arguments you passed to make are 'make me a sandwich', and if they aren't, call make with all of it's args.

if you want to tell make to run a rule for certain args:

```
if [ $1 = 'foo' ]; then
    make somerule
fi
```