# make with argument for different executable name

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake

I have a c++ codebase. I have a CMakeLists. When I run `make`, it creates the binary `myexec`.

I would like to be able to run, say, `make -- v2`, and that it creates the exact same binary, but called `myexec_v2`. It would be great if it did not have to recompile everything to create this binary, but only the modified files.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not an answer, but couldn't a possible workaround be to write a small script that does 1) make and then 2) rename/copy `myexec` based on the argument using either 'move' or 'copy', whichever is suitable?

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273608/how-to-pass-argument-to-makefile-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

```
myexec myexec_v2: $(prerequisites)
    @echo compile $@
```

observe:

```
$ make myexec
compile myexec
$ make myexec_v2
compile myexec_v2
```

if nothing else is needed to compile `myexec_v2` then you are done.

see here for more information: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html

here is a slightly more advanced version

```
myexec myexec_v2: myexec%: $(prerequisites)
    @echo compile $@ $*
```

this is called a static pattern rule. the `myexec%` in the middle is called the target pattern. in this example we only use it to get the so called stem. the stem would be `_v2` and the variable `$*` expands to the stem.

for more information: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html

observe:

```
$ make myexec
compile myexec
$ make myexec_v2
compile myexec_v2 _v2
```

now you can use either `$@` or `$*` in the recipe to modify the behaviour to compile on or the other.

but if you want to do if branches in the recipe read this first: [Basic if else statement in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602758/basic-if-else-statement-in-makefile)