# Makefile: exit on conditional

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to check that an environment variable is set before executing some code in a Makefile. If it's not set I want to throw an error with a simple error message:

```
run:
  [ -z "$(MY_APP)" ] && echo "MY_APP must be set" && exit 1
  echo "MY_APP is set. Yay!"
  echo "Let's continue on with the command..."
```

When `MY_APP` is not set I get the following error, which is desired:

```
[ -z "" ] && echo "MY_APP must be set" && exit 1
MY_APP must be set
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

However, when `MY_APP` is set I get the following error:

```
[ -z "EXAMPLE_NAME" ] && echo "MY_APP must be set" && exit 1
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? And is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that the `&&` condition require that all conditions must be **TRUE** to pass. Since the first condition fail, the whole command will return a status of `1` (-> **false**), effectively stopping the make

You can use the following, so that the test will fail only when `MY_APP` is missing.

Note that I'm using `false` instead of `exit 1`. Also better to use `"${MY_APP}"`, which make it easier to copy/paste from Make to shell prompt/script.

```
run:
    { [ -z "$(MY_APP)" ] && echo "MY_APP must be set" && false } || true
    ...

# Or just if-Then-Else
    if [ -z "${MY_APP}" ] ; then echo "MY_APP must be set" ; false ; fi
    ...
```

Comment: The simple rule is, you almost always want to use `||` in makefile recipes, not `&&`.  That means inverting your tests, sometimes (remember your boolean logic!).  In this case you can use: `[ -n "$(MY_APP)" ] || { echo "MY_APP must be set"; exit 1; }`

Answer (score 3):

You can test environment variables with [Makefile conditional syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html), like this:

```
sometarget:
ifndef MY_APP
    @echo "MY_APP environment variable missing"
    exit 1
endif

    somecommand to_run_if_my_app_is_set
```

Note that `ifndef`/`ifdef` operate on the *name* of the variable, not the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use a Makefile to run commands which are not building targets (the target name `run` is a giveaway). You already got bitten by one of Makefile and shells caveats. Makefile caveat: exit status is inspected after each line and if not zero abort immediately. Shell caveat: the `test` command (`[`) returns a non zero exit status so the entire line returns non zero.

The rule of thumb is: a recipe of a rule should create a filename named like the target of the rule.

Here is a rule (to clarify the terms):

```
target:
  recipe command lines
  should create file named target
```

There are some exceptions to this rule of thumb. Most notably `make clean` and `make install`. Both typically do not create files named `clean` or `install`. One can argue that `make run` maybe also be an exception to this rule of thumb.

If your `run` is as simple as a typical `clean` then I might agree about making an exception. But usually commands are run with command line arguments. Before long you will want `make run` accept arguments. And making make accept custom command line arguments is not fun at all.

You tried to manipulate the behaviour using environment variables which is somewhat less problematic than command line arguments. But still problematic enough to make you trip over a caveat.

My suggestion for a fix:

- Put complex recipes in a shell script. There you have all the power and flexibility of a shell script without the awkwardness of makefiles. For example as explained here: [Basic if else statement in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602758/basic-if-else-statement-in-makefile/58651614#58651614)
- In case of a typical `run` target write a wrapper shell script around the makefile which lets the makefile rebuild the target and then run the target. For exampe as explained here: [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run/45003119#45003119)

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally exit the Makefile using `error` control function, at least in the *GNU* version.

This snippet is a helpful condition to put into the head of the *Makefile*. It exits with a message of help, if `make` was not called from within the directory of the *Makefile*.

```
MAKEFILE_DIR:=$(shell dirname $(realpath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
ifneq (${MAKEFILE_DIR}, $(shell pwd))
 INVALID_LOCATION:=`make` must be called from within ${MAKEFILE_DIR} (or with option -C ${MAKEFILE_DIR})
 $(error ERROR: $(INVALID_LOCATION))
endif
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html

Useful in case your paths are relative to the *Makefile* and you don't want them to prefix with a base.