# How to pass input parameters to make?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have very specific instructions:

I am to write a code in c++ that runs from the command line as follows:

`make compile`

`make run file.txt alpha > output.txt`

Currently, I know how to write a make file to run the compiled code...

```
run:
    ./my_program.exe
```

But how would I write a makefile such that the make file runs:

```
./my_program file.txt alpha
```

When I type:

```
make run file.txt alpha
```

??

Comment: Makefiles are not really designed for running programs. Why not just run the program?

Comment: @Galik not really sure why.  I'm still in school...it is a turn in requirement for an assignment...is there a way I can hack it?

Comment: So you just want to pass variables into make? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make

Comment: @Tuffwer the assignment specifies exactly the line in the question (don't see a backtick on the cellphone keyboard):  make run input1 input2

Comment: @Tuffwer since it'll be an auto grader, I'm thinking there isn't too much flexibility...

Comment: Will this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6273809/5220640

Comment: Will the grader actually vary those parameters?

Comment: @Tuffwer wow.  that was a find (guess not, actually--105 upvotes). thank you though--worked; just had to change some stuff.  you think I should leave this up, link that answer, and mark as duplicate? Or delete?

Comment: It is asking the same thing so a duplicate would fit.   In terms of the solution really it's a bit of a hack. An alternative approach (which is where I think @Beta was going) is if you just have to have it run with that specific string you could have a run target that just hard codes those parameters, but without knowing for sure that seems to be a risk.

Comment: @Tuffwer ah, ok.  yeah, I think that I'm going to go with this for now, and talk to a TA next week. Thanks man.  Looking for a book on make as we speak :)