# Stop executing makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I implement a recipe in order to pass all the remaining string to the command, as example in this script:

<kbd>Makefile</kbd>

```
run:
#   ./bin/run.sh $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS)) 
    @echo $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

But when I run as example:

```
>make run my custom input params
my custom input params
make: *** No rule to make target `my'.  Stop.
```

makefile try to execute also the remaining string so the error:

> ```
> make: *** No rule to make target `my'.  Stop.
> ```

How can I prevent this?

NB: As workaround I define a dummy recipe:

```
%:
    @echo
```

So this will print an empty string instead of the error.

I want to avoid to do something like:

```
make run-example param="my custom param"
```

Comment: `make` takes a list of targets on the command line. Maybe you are asking about how to change the list of targets?

Comment: From the (GNU) make man page: _make [OPTION]... [TARGET]..._ . Hence, you ask make to build the targets _run_, _my_, _custom_, _input_ and _params_.

Comment: @Corion i'm passing as list of target a list of params, so i don't want the makefile try to execute this list

Comment: @user1934428 yes, exactly, I want to stop the execution of the other list after the first. I try with `exit` without any success

Comment: @Matteo : I guess make is checking the existence of all targets initially. If you don't want make to build these targets, why do you write them on the command line of the make command?

Comment: I want to avoid to do something like: `make run-example param="my custom param"`

Comment: But that's how `make` works. I think the best approach is to start working with make instead of against it. Maybe write a shell script wrapper that converts `matteo-make.sh run my custom param` to `make run param="my custom param"` ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273608/how-to-pass-argument-to-makefile-from-command-line/6273809

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you should use a Makefile. You want to do your own parsing of the options, and that's more trouble to do in make.

If you're dead set on it, you could do this:

```
%:
    @true
```

...which will avoid printing an empty line.

It would be better to do this in Bash, though. Here's one way you could do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo Not enough args
    exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
    "run")
        shift
        ./bin/run.sh $@
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Command $1 not recognized"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

This seems easier and more extensible.

Comment: make sense, thanks Nick, I prefer using it passing as options

Answer (score 11):

You can probably achieve what you want with a [match-anything rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules). Example (using a dummy `printf` recipe instead of a real one):

```
PARAMS := $(filter-out run,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

run:
    @printf './bin/run.sh $(PARAMS)\n'

%:;
```

Demo:

```
$ make run my custom input params
./bin/run.sh my custom input params
make: 'my' is up to date.
make: 'custom' is up to date.
make: 'input' is up to date.
make: 'params' is up to date.
```

You can ignore the `make: 'target' is up to date.` messages or use the `--quiet` option (or `--silent` or `-s`):

```
$ make --quiet run my custom input params
./bin/run.sh my custom input params
```

If your Makefile is more complex than this, the match-anything rule could be a problem because it could catch other targets that you do not want to be caught. In this case make conditionals are an option:

```
ifeq ($(SECONDPASS),)
PARAMS := $(filter-out run,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

run:
    @$(MAKE) --quiet $@ PARAMS='$(PARAMS)' SECONDPASS=true

%:;
else
run:
    @printf './bin/run.sh $(PARAMS)\n'

# other rules if any
endif
```

Finally, if the name of the first goal is not always the same, you can adapt this with:

```
GOAL   := $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))
PARAMS := $(filter-out $(GOAL),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

$(GOAL):
    @printf './bin/$(GOAL).sh $(PARAMS)\n'

%:;
```

Or:

```
GOAL   := $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))

ifeq ($(SECONDPASS),)
PARAMS := $(filter-out $(GOAL),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

$(GOAL):
    @$(MAKE) --quiet $@ PARAMS='$(PARAMS)' SECONDPASS=true

%:;
else
$(GOAL):
    @printf './bin/$(GOAL).sh $(PARAMS)\n'

# other rules if any
endif
```

Demo:

```
$ make --quiet nur foo bar
./bin/nur.sh foo bar
```

Comment: There is not need to use `--quiet` to suppress the messages `make: 'target' is up to date`. You can define `@:` inside your target `run` and it will suppress that message.   See an example and more references on [Force Makefile to execute script after building any target (just before exiting)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58359772/4934640)

Answer (score 2):

You can always pass / set ENV variables before executing make if you only want to pass variables to make or to a shell script.

```
MYPARAM1=123 MYPARAM2=456 make
```

OR using a subshell

```
(MYPARAM1=123; MYPARAM2=456; echo A=$MYPARAM1 B=$MYPARAM2; make)
(export MYPARAM1=123; export MYPARAM2=456; A=$MYPARAM1 B=$MYPARAM2; make) // exporting
```

You might also look at the [bash-shell-special-parameters](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-shell-special-parameters/)