# How to compile C program with variable name using Linux terminal?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Is there any possible way to compile C program in a more efficient manner than running whole command.

```
gcc -g -Wall file_name.c -o file_name.out
```

For example to use make command in this way: `make argument.c`

I want the make command to run this command `gcc -g -Wall argument.c -o argument_no_extension.out`

I was trying to learn vim but to compile program I have to write down whole command or have to use arrow keys to run it again . But vs-code task.json which have the following arguments:

```
"gcc","-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o","${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out", "&&", "clear" , "&&" , "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
```

Comment: the keyword you are looking for is certainly *makefile*

Comment: Yes , I know makefile is used to run make command but I don't know how to make a makefile for this purpose.

Comment: Conventionally, apart from the default output from the C compilers `a.out`, programs don't have an extension on Unix systems.  You don't have to type `ls.out` or anything like that.  You can type `make file_name` and it will compile from `file_name.c`.  You can set the compilation options, too.  If you really insist on `.out` extensions, you can write a rule to create a `.out` file from a `.c` file.

Comment: In short you are asking me to drop .out extension and just name executable based on file_name .

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you can already do

```
make file_name
```

and it will, using default build rules (so you don't even need a Makefile), build an executable called "file_name" if there is a C source file called "file_name.c"

if you really do need the executable to have the .out extension you could create a Makefile that looks like this

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall

%.out: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

This defines a rule that for anything that ends in ".out" it will build it from the corresponding ".c" file. So if you type

```
make file_name.out
```

as above it will build "file_name.out" if you have a "file_name.c"

Comment: Sir can you please explain $@ and $^ and thanks for answering . As mentioned in other comment i don't think .out extension is necessary for making an executable . I have also tried an alternative method by making a bash script "gcc -g -Wall $1.c -o $1 " . Can you tell me advantages of make over a bash script.

Comment: `$@` is replaced with the filename on the left hand side of the rule - the thing you're building. `$^` is the files on the right (the dependencies).

Comment: As for why to use `make` - it's a standard tool used by programmers for decades and unlike your script, it knows when it needs to build something or not. If you try `make something` twice, it will only compile "something" once where as your script will re-compile everything. You'll find it indispensable when you have multiple source and header files compiling into one executable

Comment: What does %.out: %.c do?

Comment: That was covered in the answer

Comment: I tried to make a "makefile" with your instruction and passed file_name.out as argument to make command but it throws error: *** No rule to make target 'helloworld.out'.  Stop. but when i tried "make helloworld" then it generated an executable with helloworld but then i again tried "make helloworld.out" again then it generated helloworld.out using copy command on previous executable (helloworld) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209571/discussion-between-utkarsh-singh-and-chris-turner).

Comment: Sounds like you called the file the wrong name - it should be called "Makefile" (with a capital M)

Comment: No, actually it was Makefile only

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `Makefile`which should contain the command as you shown

```
gcc -g -Wall file_name.c -o file_name.out
```

Place this `Makefile` in the directory where the source code is there.
Then open the command line and change the directory to the location where this `Makefile` is there.

Then execute this command

```
make
```

No need to give `make argument.c`

Comment: But problem arises when i need to compile file of different name such as fact.c or stackoverflow.c then every time i have to make a separate make file but i want to make a general make file which accepts name of file as argument for make command and just execute gcc command .

Comment: For that you have to create some script for running the makefile. Can u please have a look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273608/how-to-pass-argument-to-makefile-from-command-line

Comment: Well, that's not what your question asks for.

Comment: @MadScientist Sorry I was unable to explain my question well . Sir i checked your profile you seems to be a veteran emacs user . Currently i am learning vim , should i try emacs also . If yes , then why?

Comment: I'm not sure SO comments are the best place to discuss.  Emacs vs. vi is one of the oldest arguments out there among programmers... I can't answer in 500 characters.  vi is good to learn, at least enough to get around, since it's installed everywhere.  If you need an editor for real work you should try Emacs and see.  I've found that preference is somewhat personal.  Some people like modal editing.  Some don't.  Some like a single editor that runs for days/weeks with lots of buffers, some like stopping/starting.  Emacs has some fantastic modes, including Viper if you like vi modal editing.

Comment: Sorry for asking such question in comments which are completely off topic but I just wanted a one-to-one interaction with a emacs user and their view on vim . But thanks for providing with such a precise explanation in the given word limit.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a Makefile similar to:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -ggdb

%.out : %$(parm).c
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Then to run the Makefile for a specific *.c file use:

```
make -Dparm=<desired file name>
```