# make, variables depend on target

Tags: makefile, gnu

Makefile

```
abc:
TEST=$@ /* TEST=abc */

def:
TEST=$@ /* TEST=def */

xxx:
        @echo $(TEST)
```

If I run `make abc xxx`, I 
expect output `abc`.

If I run `make def xxx`, I
expect output `def`.

But it doesn't work like that. It seems like `make` won't let me define a variable in target. My question is how could I define a variable and its value which depend on which target is built?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to "make run"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run)

Comment: As written, the two `TEST` macro assignments are processed as the file is read, and the second 'wins'.  Note that the macro includes the C comment; when I run `make abc xxx`, the output starts with xxx, includes all the names in my root directory, `TEST=def` and `*/`.  When you're building `abc`, there is no command to be executed.  Ditto `def`.  When you build `xxx`, the value of `$@` is `xxx`.  You can't easily make `xxx` output a value that depends on what else was built earlier in the same run of `make`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: the suggested duplicate question seems to be very different from what this is asking about (if I understand what this is asking about).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'm sorry I forgot mention to remove c comments. you are right. but how could make define a variable depends on target? I hope TEST is processed when target is build, rather than file is read.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU Make, you can duplicate the intended result of your Makefile as follows:

```
echo.%:
    @echo $*
```

or simply:

```
%:
    @echo $*
```

These would allow you to specify `make echo.abc` or `make abc`, respectively, and see `abc` as output.

That's all well and good, but it sounds like you would be more interested in target-specific variables. If the variable value is dependent on, but not a substring of, the target name, you can do something like this:

```
%:
    @echo $(TEST)

abc: TEST=xyzzy

def: TEST=plugh
```

This allows you to specify `make abc` and see `xyzzy` as output.

---

If you want to go beyond this, so that the behavior of a target changes based on what other targets are specified on the command line, we have two options: either have `.PHONY` targets that update a file used by your primary target, or do some processing of the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable:

Option 1:

```
xxx: xxx.temp
    @cat xxx.temp
    @rm xxx.temp

abc def:
    @echo $@ > xxx.temp

.PHONY: xxx abc def
```

This relies on the fact that the command line goals are processed in order (*If you specify several goals, make processes each of them in turn, in the order you name them.* -GNU Make Manual, section 9.2), so you must specify `make abc xxx` and not `make xxx abc`.

Option 2:

```
ifneq (,$(findstring abc,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    VAR=abc
else ifneq (,$(findstring def,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    VAR=def
endif

xxx:
    @echo $(VAR)

abc def:
    @echo -n > /dev/null

.PHONY: xxx abc def
```

The `@echo -n > /dev/null` suppresses the `make: Nothing to be done for 'abc'.` message. This seems much clumsier to me, and I would recommend Option 1 if you can tolerate the temp file.

Comment: Thank you laindir. I'm getting closer.

Comment: foo:
 @echo $(TEST)

abc: TEST=xxx
def: TEST=yyy

Comment: foo:
 @echo $(TEST)

abc: TEST=xxx
def: TEST=yyy

make abc foo
expect see xxx, but won't.

how to let foo target see abc:TEST?

Comment: Target-specific variables are only in scope while the rule for the corresponding target is being run (i.e., it's in scope for the `abc` rule, but not for the `foo` rule. If you want the actions of one target to depend on what other targets are being built, you'll need to either modify a file (I'll see if I can edit with an example of that), or do some checking of `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14061796/1257631)