# Makefile how to specify program arguments

Tags: linux, makefile

I have written a small c program and created a Makefile to compile and execute it. Basically,
I do the following:

```
$ make
$ make run
```

But, my executable requires some arguments, so I would like to specify them this way:

```
$ make run arg1 arg2
```

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Have a look here if it helps you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run

Comment: Does the executable need these arguments to compile? Or just to execute? I usually use Make to compile, then ./executable arg1 arg2.

Comment: One more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make

Comment: No, I just want to use make run arg1 instead of ./executable arg1

Comment: Can we take a look of Makefile

Comment: @Satish, it is a trivial Makefile. Just all target, with gcc x.c -o x and run target with ./x.

Comment: Is there a reason that `make run` is easier than `./myProg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

Makefile

```
 demo: demo1.c
            cc -o demo1 demo1.c
 run:
            ./demo1 $A $B
```

Passing argument as a variable `A` and `B`

```
[spatel@mg0008 tmp]$ make run A=2 B=3
./demo1 2 3
2 + 3 = 5
```