# what is $(-*-command-variables-*-)) in gnu make

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu

In my project makefile, there is a variable named "-*-command-variables-*-". I could guess its meaning from the context, but I want to know more about "-*-command-variables-*-". No result from google and GNU make manual.

Here is my test makefile,

```
all:
    $(warning $(-*-command-variables-*-))
    #$(warning $(.VARIABLES))
    #$(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), $(info $v===>$($v)))
```

When I type `make test=Makefile`, it prints out:

```
Makefile:2: test=Makefile
make: `all' is up to date.
```

I found this variables is in .VARIABLES variable, but I can not find it in GNU manual.
The version of make I used is GNU make 3.81.
Can anyone tell me where does this variables defined in or more about these variables? Thank you.

Comment: This is a user variable. It must has been set somewhere in your Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one internal variable defined in main.c (line 1344),

```
/* Define an unchangeable variable with a name that no POSIX.2
   makefile could validly use for its own variable.  */
(void) define_variable ("-*-command-variables-*-", 23,value, o_automatic, 0);
```