# Run each Command individually but distribute them in Multiple Make-files

Tags: makefile

- I wanted to have every Env have its own `Makefile` (local, dev, production).
- So I created 3 directories and a `Makefile` for every Directory.
- Then creates a common `MakeFile` which includes all other child `Makefiles` as :

[image: makefile]

- I was able to include my child commands in Parent file but the issue is

  - If I ran `make local` , it executes all commands inside Makefile.local
  - But instead I want each command must be ran individual
  - When mentioned like `make local local_command` or even `make local_command` , `local_command` must be executed only.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run

Comment: @Jérôme It is taking argumnet , I don't think so It will run child command

Comment: If you're using GNU Make, why not `include` your makefiles into the main makefile?

Answer (score 0):

You likely want something like:

```
TOP_LEVEL_TARGS := dev local prod

$(TOP_LEVEL_TARGS):
    make -f config/local/Makefile.$@ $(filter-out $(TOP_LEVEL_TARGS), $(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

This will invoke a sub-make with all the command goals of the original make commands (minus the top level targets).