# How to call pandoc from makefile on different files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a writing project and would like to use `make` for running `pandoc` on files. So far I've tried to pass arguments to `make` like I do with a bash script.

For example:

```sh
$ make chapter 2
```

In the make file `chapter` is the target and `2` would be the argument.

I don't know if makefiles have the facility to take cli arguments. I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.htm).

So far I have tried to run make with this recipe.

```
chapter:
    @pandoc -s -o "$1.epub" "$1.md"
```

I get this error back

```sh
pandoc: .md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
make: *** [Makefile:2: chapter] Error 1
```

*This is for turning sections of a book I'm working on into epubs. I'm open to other ways to do this with make seeing as tokens don't to work.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the make file chapter is the target and 2 would be the argument

```
$ make chapter num=2
```

The assignment to variables on the *make* command-line overrides any definition inside the makefile
(yep, such variables effectively become read-only).
This suggests a makefile something like:

```
num = $(error You must set $$num to the chapter number you want (make chapter num=4))

.PHONY: chapter
chapter:
    pandoc -s -o "${num}.epub" "${num}.md"
```

What's going on here?
Well, if you forget to set *num*,
when *make* expands the recipe for *chapter* the
`$(error)` will cause *make* to stop.

```
$ make
Makefile:5: *** You must set $num to the chapter number you want (make chapter num=4).  Stop.
```

And your original example?

```
$ make chapter num=2
pandoc -s -o "2.epub" "2.md"
```

### Tips

- I rarely recommend using the `@` prefix — Users can use *make*'s `-s` if they don't want to see the shell commands
- Don't lie to *make* — In particular, your rule does not produce a file called `chapter`, so please tell *make* that by marking the target `.PHONY`

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for. I'm new to Makefiles. I was wondering if you knew of a way to include `-s` in the Makefile, seeing as using `@` prefix is not good?

Comment: `@` is fine, but how do you remove them all if you actually want to see the commands? (for debugging say). I suppose you could do a `q := @` at the top, and then start every recipe line with `$q` (`$qecho hello` for instance) — single character macros don't need to be surrounded in `{` and `}`. [Forcing `-s` is rather like forcing `-j5`. Really it should up to the user IMHO.]

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to say this in Make is to enumerate all the chapters as targets, typically as dependencies for `make all`.

So basically

```
src := $(wildcard *.md)
epubs := $(patsubst %.md,%.epub,$(src))

.PHONY: all
all: $(epubs)

%.epub: %.md
    pandoc -s -o $@ $<
```

You can say `make ch4.epub` if you have a chapter whose source is `ch4.md`. You can't really pass in an argument which isn't a file name or a target name, and these cannot contain spaces.

I suppose you could add a phony like

```
.PHONY: 2
2: ch2.epub
```

to be able to say `make 2` and have it mean `make ch2.epub`. If file names are systematically named like this, you could generalize to

```
short := $(patsubst ch%.md,%,$(src))
.PHONY: $(short)
$(short): %: ch%.epub
```

Don't use `@` in front, it just makes things harder. You can use `make -s` if you don't want to see the output and not wreck your `Makefile`.

Comment: I like your solution. When I tried `$ make forward.epub`, I got back `Makefile:7: *** mixed implicit and static pattern rules. Stop.` Could this be a problem with the directory lay out?

Comment: Sorry, I had a colon too much in the dependency declaration; fixed now.