# Using command line input in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I currently have a makefile that when run will link a .h and .c file and then create a binary. Is it possible to make the makefile execute this binary by just doing make followed by an input file_name ?

My makefile looks something like this:

```
CC = g++
cppflags = "-std=c++0x"
all : interpreter

byte.o : opcode.h byte.h byte.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(cppflags) byte.cpp
interpreter : byte.o main.cpp
 $(CC) $(cppflags) byte.o main.cpp -o interpreter
```

If I do `make` I'll get an executable `interpreter` that takes the name of an input file as an argument. What I want to do is modify my makefile so that I can do `make <file_name>` making the makefile run the executable instead of having to use the binary created by the make I already have. The input file name can not be hard coded.

Comment: Please show a mcve of your make and how you invoke.

Comment: At first read, if I understand it, my answer is yes it is possible to do something like that..  I do it a lot.  But on Linux, and the text to invoke your new app is specific to whether the app is local or in some other dir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example:

```
  a : a.c
          gcc a.c -o a.o
          ./a.o
  b : b.c
          gcc b.c -o b.o
          ./b.o
```

when you run "make a", a.o executable. "make b", b.o executable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you invoke make on a target to create (e.g., `make interpreter`), and not on the input file (which make does not known how to build). One common way to address this is to define a (rule-based) target for executing the code. For example .res ('.res' for result). The target will run the program and save the output to the `.res` file.

You will invoke the target with make input_file_name.res

```
%.res: % interpreter
    interpreter $< > $@
```

Note explicit dependency to build interpret before running this target.

See make 'explicit' variables for more information on `$<` (input file), and `$@` (output file)

Answer (score 0):

don't try to make make accept arguments other than targets to build.

instead create script:

```
#! /bin/sh
# rebuild if necessary
make
# run interpreter with arguments
interpreter "$@"
```

and run with arguments:

```
$ ./buildtheninterpret.sh filenametointerpret
```

for more explanation why do this and caveats of makefile hackery read my answer to another similar question: [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run/45003119#45003119)