# Is it possible to pass a CLI flag to Make?

Tags: docker, symfony, makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile, to which I have added the following two targets that run Symfony commands inside a Docker container:

```
amqp-poll: ## Start amqp polling
    @$(DOCKER_COMPOSE) exec -it $(SERVICE_CONTAINER) /bin/bash -c "php /code/backend/app-new/console amqp:poll"

amqp-purge: ## Purge amqp queues
    @$(DOCKER_COMPOSE) exec -it $(SERVICE_CONTAINER) /bin/bash -c "php /code/backend/app-new/console amqp:poll --purge"
```

Is it possible to pass in a flag so that I am, for example, running `make amqp-poll --purge` rather than `make amqp-purge`?

In other words, I would like to merge these two targets, with the use of a double-dash flag selectively triggering the logic in the second target.

(I looked into `ifdef`, but it looks like that requires a value, right? I'm more interested in a simple flag.)

Is this possible?

Comment: The only possible syntax is `make amqp-poll my_flags=--purge`.

Comment: If the goal is to be DRY, you can use a [canned recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html) with [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Makefile:

```
# Optional default initialization to suppress warnings
AMQP_FLAGS ?=

amqp-poll: ## Start amqp polling
    @$(DOCKER_COMPOSE) exec -it $(SERVICE_CONTAINER) /bin/bash -c "php /code/backend/app-new/console amqp:poll $(AMQP_FLAGS)"
```

Command-line:

```
make amqp-poll AMPQ_FLAGS=--purge
```