# How to write a Makefile to test multiple Unittest targets?

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to write a generic Makefile that can run multiple different unit tests based on a second term in the make command.

Basically I would like to write something like:

```
make test target1 # runs unit tests for target 1
make test target2 # runs unit tests for target 2
      :
      :
      :
make test all     # runs all unit tests
```

but I can't find any documentation on how to do this. What I have right now is:

```
.PHONY: clean test
test-target1:
        pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=a .\target1\
test-target2:
        pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=b .\target2\
test-all:
        ### I don't know what to put here ###
```

but this syntax requires you to use `make test-target1` with the hyphen included.

EDIT:

Based on some really good advice I now have the updated Makefile:

```
a: # ...
    pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=a.\UnitTest\a

.PHONY: test
test : $(RUN_ARGS)
    @echo "Running unittests for $(RUN_ARGS)..."
```

but running `make test a` returns

```
Running unittests for ...
make: 'a' is up to date.
```

and if I change `a` to `a1` then `make test a1` will run the actual unittests. Why is the `a` RUN_ARGS not allowed?

For reference, the structure of the code is:

```
src/a
src/b
src/UnitTest
src/UnitTest/a
src/UnitTest/b
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run) should answer how to avoid the hyphen (passing arguments to make targets). For the `I don't know what to put here` comment: the answer is written by @theherk below.

Comment: That question helped a lot. I have edited the format, but now I am having a different issue: some `$(RUN_ARGS)` values work, but others don't.

Comment: `make` interprets all its non-option arguments as the names of targets to build.  Targets, such as `test`, do not have their own arguments.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for that explanation. I was able to fix this new issue by adding `a` and `b` to `.PHONY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the help I received, I was able to solve both parts of my question by creating the following `Makefile`:

```
all: a b c

a: 
    pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=a .\UnitTest\a\

b: 
    pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=b .\UnitTest\b\

c: 
    pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=c .\UnitTest\c\

.PHONY: test a b c

test : $(RUN_ARGS)
    @echo "Running unittests..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Just depend on the other test targets.

```
test-a:
    $(info $@)

test-b:
    $(info $@)

test-all: test-a test-b
```

You could maybe simplify this very slightly, by using a pattern to match your test targets. Like this:

```
tests := $(patsubst %,test-%,a b)

test-a:
    $(info $@)

test-b:
    $(info $@)

.PHONY: $(tests)
test-all: $(tests)
```

Where `make test-all` yields:

```
❮ make test-all
test-a
test-b
make: Nothing to be done for `test-all'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use automatic variables (`$*`) and target-specific variables (`COV`) for the parameters. Example for the test rules you show in your first attempt:

```
.PHONY: clean test
TARGETs := target1 target2 ...

test-%:
    pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=$(COV) .\$*\

test: $(addprefix test-,$(TARGETS))

test-target1: COV=a
test-target2: COV=b
```