# What does "all" stand for in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I read some tutorials concerning Makefiles but for me it is still unclear for what the target "all" stands for and what it does.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

A build, as Makefile understands it, consists of a lot of targets.  For example, to build a project you might need

1. Build file1.o out of file1.c
2. Build file2.o out of file2.c
3. Build file3.o out of file3.c
4. Build executable1 out of file1.o and file3.o
5. Build executable2 out of file2.o

If you implemented this workflow with makefile, you could make each of the targets separately.  For example, if you wrote

```
make file1.o
```

it would only build that file, if necessary.

The name of `all` is not fixed.  It's just a conventional name;  `all` target denotes that *if you invoke it, make will build **all** what's needed to make a complete build*.  This is usually a dummy target, which doesn't create any files, but merely depends on the other files.  For the example above, building *all* necessary is building executables, the other files being pulled in as dependencies.  So in the makefile it looks like this:

```
all: executable1 executable2
```

`all` target is usually the first in the makefile, since if you just write `make` in command line, without specifying the target, it will build the first target.  And you expect it to be `all`.

`all` is usually also a `.PHONY` target.  Learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile).

Answer (score 43):

The manual for GNU Make gives a clear definition for `all` in its [list of standard targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets).

If the author of the Makefile is following that convention then the target `all` should:

1. Compile the entire program, but not build documentation.
2. Be the the default target.    As in running just `make` should do the same as `make all`.

To achieve 1 `all` is typically defined as a `.PHONY` target that depends on the executable(s) that form the entire program:

```
.PHONY : all
all : executable
```

To achieve 2 `all` should either be the first target defined in the make file or be assigned as the default goal:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure it stands for anything special.  It's just a convention that you supply an 'all' rule, and generally it's used to list all the sub-targets needed to build the entire project, hence the name 'all'.  The only thing special about it is that often times people will put it in as the first target in the makefile, which means that just typing 'make' alone will do the same thing as 'make all'.

Answer (score 4):

The target "all" is an example of a dummy target - there is nothing on disk called "all". This means that when you do a "make all", make always thinks that it needs to build it, and so executes all the commands for that target. Those commands will typically be ones that build all the end-products that the makefile knows about, but it could do anything.

Other examples of dummy targets are "clean" and "install", and they work in the same way.

If you haven't read it yet, you should read the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), which is also an excellent tutorial.