# Where does 'All' belong in a Makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Where do we put the all in a Makefiles?

I had a similar question found [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514903/makefile-what-does-all-stand-for), but I needed a little bit more details.  I also looked at the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), but got lost in the mountain of documentation. I tried the googles, but didn't find a good example. So, I did what was my last resort and tried to figure it out by hacking at a Makefile myself. I have:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

clean: 
rm -f all: ex1
```

This didn't compile my ex1 in C. Also, if I wanted to add more to this make file. Like ex1, ex2, to exercise whatever. Would I just put the all at the top and repeat the

```
rm - f whatever
```

line below clean?

Appreciate your help and assistance. Patience appreciated too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`all` is actually nothing special, just a target name commonly used. To make it work best, it should be the first target in the file. This makes it the default target, and `gmake` works the same as `gmake all`.

Normally, the `all` target has dependencies, which are the things which need to be built. E.g.

```
all: myexe
```

`rm` is related to the `clean` target (which is also nothing special, just a name commonly used). You define it this way:

```
clean:
    rm -f myexe
```

This makes it delete `myexe` when `gmake clean` is run. If you makefile builds other files, they should also be listed there.

There's a lot more to know about makefiles. Normally you would use variables and template rules, which help you avoid repeating yourself. But this is far more than a simple answer can describe.

Comment: When you talk about adding more files. I tried All: myexe1 myexe2 and All: myexe1, myexe2. What am I missing here? I almost got this and once I get this answered can consider this whole question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Defining `all: myexe1 myexe2` is good, but only tells `make` that it should build these two executables. You also need to provide rules to build `myexe1` and `myexe2`, but this is beyond this question. Maheybe [this link](http://mcs.mines.edu/Courses/csci262/INFO/Makefile_Quick_Reference.html) can help.