# Compile any C Program using just "make" (From a Makefile)

Tags: compilation, makefile, gnu, compiler-warnings

I'm learning C Programming through "Learn C the Hard Way." I am currently (for quite a long time) on Exercise 2, which can be found here: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html

In the extra credit section, there is a challenge which asks us to edit the Makefile so we can compile the .c file (ex1.c) using just the command "make". This is what the challenge exactly says:

> Create an all: ex1 target that will build ex1 with just the command make.

Through looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232714/where-does-all-belong-in-a-makefile) and a bunch of other places, this is the code I think is correct:

```
CFLAGS="-Wall" -g

all: ex1
    CFLAGS="-Wall" -g

clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the compiled file and keep getting an error:

```
cc "-Wall" -g    ex1.c   -o ex1
CFLAGS="-Wall" -g
/bin/sh: 1: -g: not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

What is happening here? What is the reason behind the error message? How can I fix this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Hmm, removing the double quotes didn't seem to do anything. The program itself is compiling, but I'm getting these weird error messages about "-g" not being found. I would really like to know what's causing this and therefore how I can fix it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- If `all` is the first target in your makefile (I'm making a wild guess here since you've not showed the entire Makefile), make would choose that as the first target to build, when you do not pass an explicit target from the command line (i.e. mere `make`)
- `ex1` is a pre-requisite for `all`, so it builds it first and hence you see the following line:

  ```
  cc "-Wall" -g    ex1.c   -o ex1
  ```
- After `ex1` is built, make tries to execute the recipe for all, where it executes the following command:

  ```
  CFLAGS="-Wall" -g
  ```
- Since `-g` by itself is not a valid command or application that can be executed in the shell, you get this error:

  ```
  /bin/sh: 1: -g: not found
  ```

**Solution:**

- You've already defined `CFLAGS` in the beginning of the makefile, so no need to define it once again in the recipe. Even if you wish to override the variable `CFLAGS`, you should not be using it directly as part of the recipe.
- Define `all` and `clean` as `PHONY` targets, if you've not already done so. The target `all` and `clean` do not create a file named `all` or `clean` after the recipe is executed, so it is a good practice to classify these targets as `PHONY`.
- You don't need double quotes around `-Wall`

The following Makefile has all these corrections:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

all: ex1

clean:
    rm -f ex1

.PHONY: all clean
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

all: ex1

clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

Should be all you need since make has a built-in default rule to compile a .c file to an executable.

Your mistake is to use a variable assignment as a command. The part with

```
 CFLAGS="-Wall" -g
```

tries to run the command `-g` with a one-shot variable assignment `CFLAGS="-Wall"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest one adjustment so that you can build `ex1` just by entering `make`, regardless if this is the first compilation or a recompilaiton of the source code.

**Source:**    `ex1.c`

**Makefile:**

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all : clean ex1

clean:
    rm -rf ex1 ex1.dSYM

.PHONY: all clean
```

By adding the `clean` Phony Target as the first *prerequisite* for `all`, it will execute the `rm -rf ex1 ex1.dSYM` command prior to executing the implied `cc` command with the `ex1` prerequisite.

Also, on Mac OS-X using `.PHONY all clean` is not necessary for `make` to execute the commands in the `Makefile`, however, it is probably good precedent to set so that anyone reading the code later on realizes that all and clean are not actual target files.

Oh and a big thank you to Zed A. Shaw for making Learn the Hard Way free to read at his site [Learn C the Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html).