# Exclude a target from `make` but include in `make all` in CMake

Tags: cmake

I am aware that CMake's `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` allows me to exclude a target from both `make` and `make all`.

What if I wanted to only exclude the target from the default `make` but include it in the `make all`?

Example:

```
add_executable(aaa ${AAA_SOURCE})
add_executable(bbb EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${BBB_SOURCE})
```

Result:

`make` only builds `aaa`

`make all` only builds `aaa`

What I want:

`make` only builds `aaa`

`make all` builds `aaa` and `bbb`

Comment: Are you aware, that if you omit the target in your make call, it will automatically build all?

Comment: for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553569/how-can-i-build-multiple-targets-using-cmake-build?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using CMake with the Unix Makefiles Generator, you will get make files that have the default target `all`.
When you run `make <target>`, the `<target>` gets build. If the argument is omitted, the default target is build. Adding `all` does not mean that all targets are build, but the target called `all`.
To answer your question: As both ("" and "`all`") are the same target, you cannot add a build to one target but not to the other.

By the way, there is no clear definition what `all` should include, cf. [What does "all" stand for in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2514903/2799037)

Comment: So I assume it's not possible to create a target, say called `all`, that refers to multiple targets

Comment: You can have such a target, but you have to name it different from the build-in ones like "test", "install", or "all".

Comment: Could you tell me the CMake command for creating a target that actually refers to multiple targets?  I assume it's not `add_executable` since that only refers to 1 target..

Comment: Just create a new target and use add_dependencies. A litte complicated, but still valid answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47553569/2799037