# Compile all C files in a directory into separate programs

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way using GNU Make of compiling all of the C files in a directory into separate programs, with each program named as the source file without the .c extension?

Answer (score 61):

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)

PROGS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

all: $(PROGS)

%: %.c

        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -o $@ $<
```

Comment: @Martin brilliant! But I don't understand why you don't call PROGS and SRCS in the main line.

Comment: @user4050, sorry, I missed your question. The default `all` target builds `$(PROGS)`, and the main line says how to build files without an extension, which is what `$(PROGS)` are, from `%.c` files, which is what `$(SRCS)` are.

Answer (score 8):

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)

PROGS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

all: $(PROGS)

%: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
clean: 
        rm -f $(PROGS)
```

Improving Martin Broadhurst's answer by adding "clean" target. "make clean" will clean all executable.

Comment: You should use `.PHONY` for a target like `clean`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile for the reason.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst You should also use a `.PHONY` for target `all`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you even need a makefile - the default implicit make rules should do it:

```
$ ls
src0.c  src1.c  src2.c  src3.c
$ make `basename -s .c *`
cc     src0.c   -o src0
cc     src1.c   -o src1
cc     src2.c   -o src2
cc     src3.c   -o src3
```

Edited to make the command line a little simpler.