# What do $< and $@ mean in makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I have `a.csv`,`b.csv`, ... in a my `docs/csv` directory, I need convert each of this file to a json file.

I follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706064/compile-all-c-files-in-a-directory-into-separate-programs) to write a Makefile like this.

```
SRCS = $(wildcard docs/csv/*.csv)
DESTS = $(patsubst docs/csv/%.csv, scripts/data/%.lua, $(SRCS))

all: $(DESTS)

$(DESTS): $(SRCS)
    echo $@
    echo $<
```

but every time I ran `make all`, the `echo $@` show every file as expected, but `echo $<` always show the single file, called `items.csv` in my csv folder.

Comment: The title of your question is inaccurate-- I almost marked this a duplicate.

Comment: `make` comes with a manual, in which questions such as yours are answered. Tell us what isn't clear in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that in this rule:

```
$(DESTS): $(SRCS)
    ...
```

*every* lua file depends on *all* csv files, which is not what I think you intend. And since `$<` expands to the *first* prerequisite, you get the same one (`items.csv`) for every target.

Try this:

```
all: $(DESTS)

scripts/data/%.lua: docs/csv/%.csv 
    echo $@
    echo $<
```

Answer (score 0):

$<

is the name of the **FIRST**  dependency. Use $^ for all the dependencies

$@

is the name of the current target

Comment: I need variable match the $@, if the $@ is `scripts/data/a.lua` then I need `docs/csv/a.csv`, is there such a variable, or what's wrong with my makefile.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU make man page on [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) is extremely useful. Here's what it says:

> `$@`
>
> The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an archive member, then ‘`$@`’ is the name of the archive file. In a
>   pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern
>   Rules), ‘`$@`’ is the name of whichever target caused the rule's recipe
>   to be run.
>
> `$<`
>
> The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by
>   the implicit rule (see Implicit Rules).

Incidentally, you probably want to write your make rule as a *pattern rule* instead:

```
%.lua : %.csv
    <rules for making a lua from a csv>
```