# Improving Makefile so it only creates and cleans programs that have been changed/specifically requested

Tags: c, makefile

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706067/2051467) stackoverflow response, I've created a Makefile that compiles all .c files into separate executables. I've added a `clean` section that removes all programs. It now looks like:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)

PROGS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS)

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -o $@ $<
```

My questions are:

1. How would you have Makefile read additional command line arguments so that it can clean just the programs specified?

Comment: You want `clean` to only clean programs for which the `.c` files are newer than the built binaries? `make <prog>` will build just the program in question.

Comment: Changed part of the first question that asks about what you mentioned. Thanks for pointing it out. Would still appreciate an answer to the other question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `clean-%` target that only cleaned specific binaries or other such games but why? Your "clean" recipe is just `rm` so just run `rm` yourself.

As to building only specific binaries just run `make $binary` instead of `make` or `make all`.

All `make`/`make all` is doing is running the target for each listed binary by name.

Comment: the .c part in the question was leftover from earlier. changed it to reflect what I was asking about cleaning binaries. thanks :)