# I need help trimming down dependencies in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have created a makefile for the generation of a simple web page. The idea behind the makefile is this:

- We're compiling one web page, index.html
- index.html requires a stylus css `main.sty` that must be compiled
- There are a number of examples used in the page

  - The code for example `one` lives in `lib/examples/one`
  - Each example contains three parts

    - The markup (a `.jade` template file)
    - Some code (a `.coffee` script file)
    - A description (a `.md` markdown file)
- The build script must render each example into a single html file

  - Jade, Pygments, and Markdown are used to generate three html files
  - An `example.jade` template is used to combine these into one example file

    - `example.jade` must be copied to the correct build example directory, because the template language can only do relative imports. So in order to import `example/one/code.html`, we must copy the template to `example/one` and have it include `code.html`.
  - When finished, each example `x` will have compiled to `tbuild/examples/x.html`
- The `lib/index.jade` template is moved to `build` (so that it can include the example files)
- Jade is then used to compile the `index.jade` template into html

This is a wee bit of a simplification, but it's easier to understand this way. The simplification is that there are actually *two* markup files (left.html and right.html) in each example, and that the code file is both run through pygments *and* used as a script, so both code.html and code.coffee need to make it into build.

Right now, the makefile looks like this:

```
LIB = lib
BUILD = build
LIBEX = $(LIB)/examples
BUILDEX = $(BUILD)/examples
EXAMPLES = $(addsuffix .html,$(addprefix $(BUILDEX)/,$(shell ls $(LIBEX) | grep -v '.jade')))

all: $(BUILD)/main.css index.html

index.html: $(BUILD)/index.jade $(EXAMPLES)
    jade < $< --path $< > $@

$(BUILD)/index.jade: $(LIB)/index.jade
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp $< $@

$(BUILD)/main.css: $(LIB)/main.sty
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    stylus -u nib < $< > $@

$(BUILDEX)/%.html: $(BUILDEX)/%/template.jade $(BUILDEX)/%/left.html $(BUILDEX)/%/right.html $(BUILDEX)/%/code.html $(BUILDEX)/%/code.coffee $(BUILDEX)/%/text.html
    jade < $< --path $< > $@

$(BUILDEX)/%/template.jade: $(LIBEX)/template.jade
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp $< $@

$(BUILDEX)/%/left.html: $(LIBEX)/%/left.jade
    jade < $< --path $< > $@

$(BUILDEX)/%/right.html: $(LIBEX)/%/right.jade
    jade < $< --path $< > $@

$(BUILDEX)/%/code.html: $(LIBEX)/%/code.coffee
    pygmentize -f html -o $@ $<

$(BUILDEX)/%/code.coffee: $(LIBEX)/%/code.coffee
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp $< $@

$(BUILDEX)/%/text.html: $(LIBEX)/%/text.md
    markdown < $< > $@

clean:
    rm index.html -f
    rm $(BUILD) -rf
```

This works, but the problem is that when I touch "lib/examples/intro/code.coffee" and re-run make, I get the following:

```
mkdir -p build/examples/intro
cp lib/examples/template.jade build/examples/intro/template.jade
jade < lib/examples/intro/left.jade --path lib/examples/intro/left.jade > build/examples/intro/left.html
jade < lib/examples/intro/right.jade --path lib/examples/intro/right.jade > build/examples/intro/right.html
pygmentize -f html -o build/examples/intro/code.html lib/examples/intro/code.coffee
mkdir -p build/examples/intro
cp lib/examples/intro/code.coffee build/examples/intro/code.coffee
markdown < lib/examples/intro/text.md > build/examples/intro/text.html
jade < build/examples/intro/template.jade --path build/examples/intro/template.jade > build/examples/intro.html
jade < build/index.jade --path build/index.jade > index.html
rm build/examples/intro/right.html build/examples/intro/code.coffee build/examples/intro/code.html build/examples/intro/left.html build/examples/intro/text.html build/examples/intro/template.jade
```

Which, as you'll notice, is way more than needs to be done to regenerate the example. What I was hoping for was something more like this:

```
mkdir -p build/examples/intro
pygmentize -f html -o build/examples/intro/code.html lib/examples/intro/code.coffee
cp lib/examples/intro/code.coffee build/examples/intro/code.coffee
jade < build/examples/intro/template.jade --path build/examples/intro/template.jade > build/examples/intro.html
jade < build/index.jade --path build/index.jade > index.html
```

In other words, what I'm asking is:

1. What do I need to do to make the makefile not rebuild too much when I change something small?

   - In the above example, left.html, right.html, and text.html are all rebuilt when I touch code.coffee. How can I prevent this?
2. Why does make put the rm command at the end of the output? This seems like it might be causing some re-building where unnecessary.

Thanks for reading all the way through this beast of a question! I know that my make-fu is lacking, so any tips as to how to clean up the makefile and reduce redundancy are more than welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This build system is too large and complex to reproduce easily -- and I hate to post solutions I haven't tested -- but try adding this line:

```
.SECONDARY:
```

**EDIT:**
I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior you describe, but I can offer some pointers.

The `.SECONDARY:` is a rule; it can go anywhere in the makefile. Basically, if Make detects a chain of chain of implicit rules, A->B->C, where A is a file that exists and C is the target, it considers B an *intermediate file* and will delete it once the job is done. The `.SECONDARY:` rule blocks the deletion.

You can combine rules that have the same commands. This:

```
foo: bar
    do something $< $@

baz: quartz
    do something $< $@

quince: geef
    do something $< $@
```

can be rewritten as this:

```
foo: bar

baz: quartz

quince: geef

foo baz quince:
    do something $< $@
```

That will remove a lot of redundancy in your makefile, and perhaps make things clearer.

Comment: I know it's complex, but I couldn't find a way to simplify it and still have the dependency problems. :/ My gnu make skills are lacking. Where should the SECONDARY line be added? What does it do and why will it help? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! These are the sort of tips I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Beta mentioned, you are running into troubles with intermediate files here.

Each file that is not mentioned explicitely in the Makefile, but rather inferred via a pattern rule (a rule with `%`), is intermediate and is deleted right after make ran. And then remade on the next run.

That's the core of your "problem": The left.html and right.html files are deleted right away. Beta already mentioned that declaring them as .SECONDARY fixes this problem, like [the make manual tells you](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Special-Targets.html).

By declaring a target .SECONDARY without any prerequisites anywhere in the Makefile (really: anywhere), you declare all targets as secondary - so, no auto-deletes.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use PHONY for targets that are not files to improve the performance. Like `all` and `clean`. See here for more information: [What is the purpose of .PHONY in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile/2145605#2145605)