# how to create one makefile for 3 different c files

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am trying to create a make file for 3 c files which are `file_a.c` `file_b.c` `file_c.c` - I want to be able to do `make file_a_1` to create an executable file which I can run by typing `file_a_1`. Same for the other 2 files.

also by typing `make clean` all the `.o` files are removed. I tried this:

```
All: file_a_1 file_b_1 file_c_1

file_a_1: file_a.c
file_a.c -o file_a_1

file_b_1: file_b.c
file_b.c -o file_b_1

file_c_1: file_c.c
file_c.c -o file_c_1

clean:
rm -rf file_a_1.o
rm -rf file_b_1.o
rm -rf file_c_1.o
```

but it does not work

can someone please help me create this makefile?

Comment: You might want to look into CMAKE or other build systems that generate a lot of this for you

Comment: @DougT. good point. See this [CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefiles need tabs. I think you're also missing the invocation of your compiler. If you're doing compilation and linking in one step, there will be no object files.

```
.PHONY: all
all: file_a_1 file_b_1 file_c_1

file_a_1:
    gcc file_a.c -o file_a_1

file_b_1:
    gcc file_b.c -o file_b_1

file_c_1:
    gcc file_c.c -o file_c_1

clean:
    rm -rf file_a_1
    rm -rf file_b_1
    rm -rf file_c_1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, what is the .PHONY for?

Comment: @user2970210 [What is the purpose of .PHONY in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using tabs, as the previous poster noted, if you are doing multiple similar things, you probably want to use implicit make rules:

```
.PHONY: all clean
TARGETS = file_a_1 file_b_1 file_c_1

all: $(TARGETS)

.c:
    gcc -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGETS) *.o
```

The implicit rules (.c:) means building an executable from a .c file.  The $@ substitutes the name of the matching executable; the $< means the .c file, so if you execute "make file_a_1", the implicit rule above is applied to mean:

```
file_a_1.c:
    gcc -o file_a_1 file_a_1.c
```

Normally "make clean" will remove target executables as well.  The way you are directly linking from your gcc command, you probably won't have any *.o files anyway.

Comment: Good point about the last step, that slipped my mind.