# How to use makefile to create test results

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a C program - `example.c` and once it compiles I want to use it to generate test results.
Each file under `./tests/%.in` is a test case.

And I want from each of them to create `./tests/%.out`

I tried something like that:

```
all: test_results

example: example.c
    gcc example.c -o example

test_results: example ./tests/%.out

./tests/%.out: ./tests/%.in
   ./example $^ > $@
```

But I get errors, and it doesn't really seem to do the job.

Comment: Can you give the exact errors you get? (Along with how you use that makefile).

Comment: No rule to make target `tests/%.out', needed by `test_results'

And in general, it seems like it's not the best way

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with your way of doing that (apart from the few errors). If indeed you only have one binary file, a bunch of test files in a folder and want one output file per test input, it seems good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is the wildcard character only in a pattern rule, if you want to get every files under a directory, use `*` along with the `wildcard` function instead:

```
all: test_results

example: example.c
    gcc example.c -o example

TEST_INPUT = $(wildcard tests/*.in)
test_results: example $(TEST_INPUT:.in=.out)

./tests/%.out: ./tests/%.in
    ./example $^ > $@
```

Also, you can get rid of the `./` prefix of your paths and may want to make the `all` and `test_results` rules [phony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile). The `example` dependency of your `test_results` rule is misplaced too (it won't update the `.out` files if `example` is outdated), it should be a dependency of the `.out` files themselves:

```
.PHONY: all
all: test_results

example: example.c
    gcc example.c -o example

TEST_INPUT = $(wildcard tests/*.in)
.PHONY: test_results
test_results: $(TEST_INPUT:.in=.out)

tests/%.out: tests/%.in example
    ./example $< > $@
```

Comment: Now I the makefile generates a file named tests/*.out

Comment: @user972014 Sorry, I forgot a few important things, I edited.

Comment: I also had removed a needed `./` in the second Makefile, that's fixed now. Sorry for the hasty answer, I tested it and it works now.