# Should I be using .PHONY or not?

Tags: makefile

I am using a makefile to run tests. I am not sure about the use of `.PHONY`. I've read this post: [What is the purpose of .PHONY in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile), but still I'm not sure.

I have the following makefile:

```

```
test:
    @# Clear console log before we start.
    @clear

    # Make sure we are not having too much modules.
    @npm prune

    # Make sure we have the required modules.
    @npm install

    @# Clear the console, so we only see the test results.
    @clear

    # Run the test.
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha-casperjs test.js --reporter=spec
```

```

My `make test` command isn't making any new files. Should I be using the `.PHONY: test` or not? But even more important, why? (or why not?)

Thank you!

Malcolm Kindermans

Comment: Those lines starting `@#` are "odd".

Comment: @trojanfoe Not really, by precending those commented lines with a `@` they are not visible in the output, only in the makefile.

Comment: They are comments and therefore ignored by everything anyway.  As I say "odd".

Comment: @trojanfoe That's kinda strange, because when I don't preceed those lines with the `@`, they are printed in the output.

Comment: If you removed the tab before them, they'd not show up either -- then they'd be `make` comments instead of shell comments. Anyway, this question seems to be answered quite extensively behind the link you posted. `test` should be phony so that `touch test; make test` doesn't claim that `test` is up to date. What exactly is still unclear?

Comment: @Wintermute Thanks! Now, nothing is unclear anymore. Actually that was all I needed to know :)

Comment: I'll (vote to) mark it as a duplicate of the link then. The top answer in that question does explain this, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Wintermute I got the answer to my question. He commented:

> If you removed the tab before them, they'd not show up either -- then they'd be make comments instead of shell comments. Anyway, this question seems to be answered quite extensively behind the link you posted. test should be phony so that touch test; make test doesn't claim that test is up to date. What exactly is still unclear?

So the answer is: "Yes, I need to add `test` to the `.PHONY`, because executing the command `touch test` would break this make command.