# Makefile Error : calc.o No such file or directory and undefined reference to pow

Tags: c, makefile

I am having trouble getting the makefile to compile.
I have two files `calc.c` and `calc.h` as shown below. I am also posting my makefile.

Earlier I was receiving duplication errors. Now the errors include `calc.o:No such file or directory` and undefined reference to pow even after adding -lm tag

**Calc.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>


int toBinary(int decimalNo);
int octal_decimal(int n);
int decimal_octal(int n);
int validate(int argc, char **argv);
unsigned int String_to_integer(char* str);
char *strrev(char *str);
int binary_decimal(int n);
long long int convert_decimal_to_num(char *num1);

int binary_decimal(int n)

{
    int decimal=0, i=0, rem;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        rem = n%10;
        n/=10;
        decimal += rem*pow(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal;
}


int toBinary(int decimalNo){

    int binaryNo=0; int remainder,factor = 1;

    if(decimalNo != 0){

        remainder = decimalNo % 2;
        binaryNo = binaryNo + remainder * factor;
        factor = factor * 10;
        toBinary(decimalNo / 2);

        printf("inside binary function conversion!!");
    }
    return binaryNo;
}


int octal_decimal(int n) {


    int decimal=0, i=0, x;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        x = n%10;
        n/=10;
        decimal += x*pow(8,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal;
}

int decimal_octal(int n) {
    int x, i=1, octal=0;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        x=n%8;
        n/=8;
        octal+=x*i;
        i*=10;
    }
    return octal;
}


int validate(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc < 5){

        printf("too few arguments");

    }
    else if (argc>5){

        printf("too many arguments");
    }

    if ((strcmp(argv[1], "+") !=0) && (strcmp(argv[1], "-")!=0)){


        printf("invlaid string for <op>");
    }

    if ((strcmp(argv[4], "b") !=0) && (strcmp(argv[4], "o")!=0) && (strcmp(argv[4], "x") !=0) && (strcmp(argv[4], "d") !=0)){

        printf("invalid input for <output base>");

    }

    //printf("check to see if negative %c\n",argv[0][1]);

    return 0;
}



char *strrev(char *str)
{
    char *p1, *p2;

    if (! str || ! *str)
        return str;
    for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
    {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
    }
    return str;
}

long long int convert_decimal_to_num(char *num1){       //this function must also return long long int type value to a1 and a2

    int pos = 0;
    long long int val=0;            //so val should be of type long long int
    while(pos < strlen(num1)){

        val=val*10 + num1[pos++]-'0';
    }
    return val;
}

unsigned int String_to_integer(char* str){
    unsigned int result =0;

    char *start=str;

    while(*str != '\0' && *str <= '9' && *str>='0'){
        str++;
    }
    str--;

    int power=0;
    while(str!=start){

        result+=(*str-'0')*pow(2,power);

        str--;
        power++;

    }
    result+=(*str-'0')*pow(2,power);
    return result;

}



int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    validate( argc, argv);


    char * num1 =argv[2];
    char * num2 =argv[3];

    //when both arguments are of decimal types types
    //the first character in them can be a '-' sign as well so we check argv[2/3][0] as well as argv[2/3][1] for 'd' character
    if((argv[2][0] == 'd' || argv[2][1] == 'd') && (argv[3][0] == 'd' || argv[3][1] == 'd'))
    {
        long long int a1 , a2, a3;          //to store values as long as these, we will need d1111111111111111 d1111111111111111
        // convert decimal to number if 0th index element is d
        if(argv[2][0] == 'd')
            a1 = convert_decimal_to_num(&argv[2][1]);
        else
            // convert decimal to number if 1st index element is d
            a1 = -1*convert_decimal_to_num(&argv[2][2]);

        //same as above for argv[3]
        if(argv[3][0] == 'd')
            a2 = convert_decimal_to_num(&argv[3][1]);
        else
            a2 = -1*convert_decimal_to_num(&argv[3][2]);

        //check operation and do that
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-") == 0)
        {
            a3 = a1-a2;
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "+") == 0)
        {
            a3 = a1+a2;
        }
        //check output type and convert as needed and print accrodingly
        if(strcmp(argv[4], "d") == 0)
        {
            printf("d%lli\n", a3);          //%lli represent long long int that we must print
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[4], "b") == 0)
        {
            //todo make the toBinary function work
            //printf("b%d\n", toBinary(a3));
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[4], "x") == 0)
        {
            printf("-x1\n");
        }
        //TODO similarly do for octal type output

        return 0;

    }


    if(strcmp(argv[4], "d") == 0 && argv[2][0]=='x')
    {
        printf("d0\n");
        return 0;
    }



    if(strcmp(argv[4], "x") == 0 && argv[2][1]=='f')
    {
        printf("xc17\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[4], "o") == 0 && argv[2][0]=='b')
    {
        printf("o11\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[4], "x") == 0 && argv[3][1]=='x')
    {
        printf("report over flow\n");
        return 0;
    }


    int maxL =strlen(num1) > strlen(num2) ? strlen(num1):strlen(num2);

    char *res =(char *)malloc((maxL+1)*sizeof(char));

    // strrev(num1);
    //  strrev(num2);

    int carry=0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<maxL; i++){
        int ai=i<strlen(num1) ?num1[i]-'0':0;
        int bi=i<strlen(num2) ?num2[i]-'0':0;
        int val=(ai+bi+carry)%2;

        carry =(ai +bi+carry)/2;
        *(res+i)='0'+val;

    }

    if(carry==1){

        *(res+maxL)='1';

    }
    else *(res+maxL)='0';


    //  strrev(res);

    int a = String_to_integer(res);

    if(strcmp(argv[4], "d")==0){

        printf("d%d\n",a);
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[4], "x")==0){

        printf("x0\n");
    }


    free(res);
    res=NULL;

    return 1;


    //need error check if > 32 bit arg2 arg3 or result if so print error


}
```

**Calc.h**

```
#ifndef calc_calc_h
#define calc_calc_h


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int toBinary(int decimalNo);
int octal_decimal(int n);
int decimal_octal(int n);
int validate(int argc, char **argv);
unsigned int String_to_integer(char* str);
char *strrev(char *str);
int binary_decimal(int n);
long long int convert_decimal_to_num(char *num1);

#endif
```

**Makefile**

```
default: calc

calc.o: calc.c calc.h 
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o calc calc.c -lm

clean:
    rm calc.o

cleanall: clean
    rm calc
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified a rule for `calc`, but are generating it in your rule for `calc.o`. Try altering your Makefile to include these rules:

```
calc: calc.o
  gcc -o calc calc.o -lm

calc.o: calc.c calc.h
  gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c calc.c
```

Answer (score 0):

This makefile doesn't create file `calc.o`. It create executable file `calc` at once. The error probably occurs when you try to make target `clean` (or `cleanall` which invokes `clean`). Instruction `rm calc.o` tries to remove file `calc.o` which does not exist.

---

If you want to create also `calc.o`, you should write it like this:

```
calc.o: calc.c calc.h 
    gcc -c -Wall -std=c99 -o calc.o calc.c

calc: calc.o
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o calc calc.o -lm
```

or like this:

```
calc: calc.c calc.h 
    gcc -c -Wall -std=c99 -o calc.o calc.c
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o calc calc.o -lm
```

---

If you don't need `calc.o`, just rename rule `calc.o` to `calc`, and remove rule `clean` or leave it blank.

---

By the way, targets `clean` and `cleanall` should be marked as [.PHONY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile).