# I'm having trouble understanding all: ex1 in Makefile? (Learn C The Hard Way)

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I'm working through `Learn C The Hard Way` and in Ex2 Extra Credit they ask you to create an `all: ex1` target that will build ex1 with just the command `make`.

This is the code I've created:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all: ex1

clean:
        rm -f ex1
```

It works.
When I run just `make` from the command line it `make`s the ex1 file. And when I run `make clean` it removes the file.

What I don't understand is why:

```
all: ex1
```

isn't:

```
all:
    make ex1
```

Where is it getting the `make` command from? The command line I guess, but then why does make clean run `rm -f ex1` and not `make rm -f ex1` and fail. It seems inconsistent to me. Can somebody explain what's going on?

Comment: heard about implicit rules in make?

Comment: Read documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/); it has a good tutorial section

Comment: Thanks! Reading GNU make now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `all` is not fixed, it's just a conventional name.  `all: target` denotes that if you invoke it, `make` will build all what's needed to make a complete build.
So in essence, you could have written `make ex1`, but if you, lets say, had 100 files (ex1, ex2, ex3...) you wouldn't want to type 100 lines, right?

`all` is usually also a [`.PHONY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile) target.

Comment: Thanks. It's starting to make sense. Will read up some more on it. Thanks for the .PHONY link too.