# why phony is not working in my makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, nmake, cl

Basically I have simple makefile in Windows. I've read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile). They are saying if I have a file named for example `clean` in the same folder of makefile and I have a command for cleaning some files in makefile and its name is clean, then makefile will not run the command. It rather shows this message

```
'clean' is up-to-date
```

Now to cope with the problem, I should add `.PHONY : clean`, therefore, even if I do have another file in the same folder called `clean`, makefile will run the actual command. This is my understanding. Adding `phony` has absolutely no effect whatsoever. It prints out this message again.

```
'clean' is up-to-date
```

This is my makefile in Windows. **Note**: I use `nmake`

```
# Specify compiler 
CC = cl.exe

# Specify flags
# /Zi -- Enable debugging    
# /O2 -- 
CFLAGS = /EHsc /c /W1 /Zi /O2

# Specify linker
LINK = link.exe

.PHONY : all
all : app

# Link the object files into a binary
app : main.o
    $(LINK) /OUT:app.exe main.o 

# Compile the source files into object files 
main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp /Fomain.o 

# Clean target
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    del *.o *.exe *.pdb
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Files in the same folder.

[image]

Comment: You never included `clean` in the PHONY list.

Comment: .PHONY is a GNU make feature. Since you've tagged `nmake`, I am assuming you are using nmake. That explains why .PHONY is not doing what you expected it to do.

Comment: @RSahu, no. I'm using nmake in Windows.

Comment: @PaulRooney, I thought this `.PHONY : clean` adds `clean` to the PHONY list? Isn't?

Comment: sorry i didn't realise that you had 2 PHONY clauses in there. It's a moot point anyway since nmake seems to not support PHONY.