# Makefile for conditional rendering of Rmarkdown files

Tags: makefile, rstudio, r-markdown, gnu-make

I am a Makefile novice and I want to use it to render Rmarkdown files when they have altered timestamps, to produce the corresponding `.pdf` files. The file `data_prep_1.Rmd` is rendered to `.pdf` and additionally produces the output file `all_sample_data.csv`. When `data_prep_1.Rmd` is changed (or its timestamp is altered), it should be re-rendered, as should `../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd` and `distance_matrices.Rmd` because they depend on the `.csv` file. If the timestamp of `../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd` is changed relative to its `.pdf`, only this `.Rmd` file should be re-rendered.

Putting the all : and the `.pdf` and `.csv` file in the first line will lead both blocks to run each time make is called.
I have:

```
../../data/all_sample_data.csv : data_prep_1.Rmd
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('data_prep_1.Rmd')"
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd')"
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('distance_matrices.Rmd')"

../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.pdf :  ../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd')"
```

If I do `touch data_prep_1.Rmd`, then `make`, the first block runs as desired.
But if I do `touch ../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd`, then `make`

I get  `make: '../../data/all_sample_data.csv is up to date'`.

I know this is clumsy use of Makefile, but how can I get the behavior I want in a single Makefile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of .PHONY in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile)

Comment: You need to add a `PHONY` target such as `all` that has `../../data/all_sample_data.csv` and `../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.pdf` as prerequisites, and is the first target in the makefile.

Comment: But then won't all the commands in the first block be run, even when only Reads_by_sample.Rmd has been changed?  I'd like to avoid rendering when the prerequisite hasn't changed.

Comment: Unless you modify `data_prep_1.Rmd` the recipes for the first rule won't be run.

Answer (score 1):

The comments above are confusing but hide the answer.

When `make` runs, it doesn't try to build every single target in the makefile. Instead, it only tries to build the *first* target in the makefile.  In your makefile the first target is `../../data/all_sample_data.csv` and so that's the only target make will try to build.

You can get it to build other targets by adding them to the command line; for example `make ../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.pdf`.

If you always want a certain set of targets what you do is create a new target as the first target in the makefile, that lists all the other targets you want to create as prerequisites.  By convention, but only convention, that target is typically called `all`.  So it would look like this:

```
all: ../../data/all_sample_data.csv ../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.pdf
.PHONY: all

../../data/all_sample_data.csv : data_prep_1.Rmd
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('data_prep_1.Rmd')"
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd')"
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('distance_matrices.Rmd')"

../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.pdf :  ../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('../bioinformatics/Reads_by_sample.Rmd')"
```

The `.PHONY` is not required but is useful, it tells make that `all` is not a real file, but rather just a dummy target in the makefile.

You should also consider creating some make variables and using [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) to simplify your makefile, for example:

```
BIODIR := ../bioinformatics
DATADIR := ../../data

all: $(DATADIR)/all_sample_data.csv $(BIODIR)/Reads_by_sample.pdf
.PHONY: all

$(DATADIR)/all_sample_data.csv : data_prep_1.Rmd
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('$<')"
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('$(BIODIR)/Reads_by_sample.Rmd')"
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('distance_matrices.Rmd')"

$(BIODIR)/Reads_by_sample.pdf :  $(BIODIR)/Reads_by_sample.Rmd
        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('$<')"
```

You can go further and use pattern rules etc. if you have lots of these types of files.

Also, it *appears* that your first target should depend not just on `data_prep_1.Rmd` but also on `distance_matrices.Rmd` and `Reads_by_sample.Rmd`; don't you want to rebuild if any of those changes?

Comment: In your last comment, you mean All should have the two .Rmd files as dependencies, right? So an additional target and dependency would be: ./geo_distances_populations.csv :  distance_matrices.Rmd
 Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('distance_matrices.Rmd')"       and the .csv file would go into all as well?

Comment: You can list all the prerequisites in the same rule line if you want.  I'm not really sure what aspect of that recipe causes the output CSV file to be created.  But you can say: `.../all_sample_data.csv : data_prep_1.Rmd distance_matrices.Rmd .../Reads_by_sample.Rmd`