# How to create a makefile for installing a dockerfile

Tags: docker, makefile, dockerfile

I have my dockerfile that contains a base image and a composer to install
and I need to create a **makefile** for installing the existing dockerfile
and I have no idea how can I create it

Comment: Containerfiles cannot be "*installed*". Do you mean "build a container-image from the containerfile"?

Comment: yes I need to build my image from dockerfile using makefile, when I launch make install I need dockerfile to be built

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a basic Makefile such as:

```
IMAGENAME=my-image

.PHONY: build all


.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

build:
        @docker build -t ${IMAGENAME} .

all: build
```

Read this [article](https://dev.to/flpslv/using-makefiles-to-build-and-publish-docker-containers-7c8) for more information, and to understand what `.PHONY` means read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145605/1807667).